# filter rows from data where column salary has string datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    id  name    salary
0   1   shyam   10000
1   2   ram     20000
2   3   ravi    abc
3   4   abhay   30000
4   5   karan   fgh
```

expected:

```
       id   name    salary
  2    3    ravi    abc
  4    5    karan   fgh
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str.contains` as follows:

```py
df_out = df[(df["name"].str.contains(r'^[A-Za-z]+$', regex=True)) &
            (df["salary"].str.contains(r'^[A-Za-z]+$', regex=True))]
```

The above logic will only match rows for which both the `name` and `salary` columns contain only alpha characters.